# Loadash :Filter from array object

Tags: lodash

We have an array of objects as such

```
var myArr = [ {name: "john", age:23, conflict:['booking', ' double booking']}
              {name: "john", age:43, conflict:['booking', ' double booking']}
              {name: "jim", age:101, conflict:['normal', ' double booking']}
              {name: "bob", age:67, conflict:['cancelled', ' double booking']} ];
```

how do I get the list of objects from myArr where conflict object have normal value in its?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `find` to get object which have `normal` in the conflict array.

```js
var myArr = [ {name: "john", age:23, conflict:['booking', ' double booking']},{name: "john", age:43, conflict:['booking', ' double booking']},{name: "jim", age:101, conflict:['normal', ' double booking']},{name: "bob", age:67, conflict:['cancelled', ' double booking']} ],
    searchWord = 'normal';

var result = _.filter(myArr, function(o) { 
  return _.find(o.conflict, function(word) { 
    return word.toLowerCase() == searchWord.toLowerCase(); 
  }); 
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```